# Sorting by multiple values that can be None

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of dictionaries (actually, a list of objects containing dictionaries) like this, representing a table:

```
rows = [
  { '11': 14,  '12':  0,  '13':  0,  '14': 20 },
  {                       '13':  8            },
  { '11':  7,                                 },
  { '11':  2,                        '14':  2 },
  {            '12':  2,  '13':  2            },
  { '11':  3,                        '14':  3 },
  { '11':  1,                        '14':  1 },
  {                       '13':  5            },
  { '11':  8,                                 },
  { '11':  0,                        '14':  0 },
  { '11':  9,                                 },
  {                                  '14': 10 },
  {                       '13': 19            },
  {                                  '14': 12 },
  {                       '13': 15            },
  {            '12':  3,  '13':  3            }
]
```

I want to sort them by each column in the table like this:

```
[
  { '11':  0,                        '14':  0 },
  { '11':  1,                        '14':  1 },
  { '11':  2,                        '14':  2 },
  { '11':  3,                        '14':  3 },
  {                                  '14': 10 },
  {                                  '14': 12 },
  { '11':  7                                  },
  { '11':  8                                  },
  { '11':  9                                  },
  { '11': 14,  '12':  0,  '13':  0,  '14': 20 },
  {            '12':  2,  '13':  2            },
  {            '12':  3,  '13':  3            },
  {                       '13':  5            },
  {                       '13':  8            },
  {                       '13': 15            },
  {                       '13': 19            }
]
```

There are a few possible 'correct' orders, but that's one of them.

I've seen and tried various solutions for this sort of thing, but they all seem to involve placing `None` at the beginning or end of the list, which I don't want. For example:

```
rows.sort(key=lambda r: [r.get(c, 0) for c in ['11', '12', '13', '14']])
```

There are certain items that can't be compared (because they have no keys in common), but a comparison function can't return 'I don't know', can it?

I'm using Python 3.5, but it would be nice to stay compatible with 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: The logic you're describing is a partial order. Sorting requires a total order. It's not well defined on partially ordered data. I don't think there's an easy way around that.

Comment: This is an interesting puzzle. I will see if I can think of a good solution.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for the elements with `'14': 10` and `'14': 12` to appear anywhere else as long as it is before `'14': 20`?

Comment: Yes, @MadPhysicist

Comment: The source data is actually in the form of a some linked lists (one per column). Having looked at topological sorting, I wonder if I should take a few steps back and take advantage of this.

Comment: I don't understand the rules of your sort.  How did '14': 12 come after '11': 3 and before '11': 7? Why are the '12' and '13' keys ranked last? In general though, of course a comparison function can handle None.  You just decide where None comes in the ordering, and write the comparison function to put it there.

Comment: There is no why, @KennyOstrom - as I say, there are several possible correct orders, the data is only partially ordered.

Comment: Okay, got it. For all elements A and B, and all keys i, if A[i] < B[i] then A<B. The sample answer you posted is what I would have done. Maybe you can elaborate on the NULL. Where else would you sort it except before or after everything else? Perhaps your sample data should show an example of this.