# Sorting by attributes that can be None

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

Let's say I have a list of items I want to sort: `items = [ item1, item2, item3 ]`. The attribute I want to use to sort them is `item.data.value`, so I'd normally go:

```
sorted(items, key=attrgetter('data.value'))
```

And that'd work just fine. However, `data` can actually be `None` so obviously I couldn't access `value`.

How do you usually deal with scenarios like this?

PS: neither [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971631/sorting-list-by-an-attribute-that-can-be-none) nor [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085672/sorting-by-multiple-values-that-can-be-none) helped.

Comment: How do you want the None values to be sorted?

Comment: Either high or low priority, I don't really mind. Putting them at the tail of the list would make more sense I guess.

Comment: You could replace the the Nones with a sentinel value like this answer suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26348624/393010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sorted(items, key=lambda i: i.data.value if i.data else 0)
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I just tried. `None` instead of `0` but I think both comparisons would evaluate to the same things.

Answer (score 3):

Use as key a *tuple*, like `(False, value)`. If value is None, then the tuple should be `(True, None)`.

Tuples are compared by their first element first, then the second, et cetera. False sorts before True. So all None values will be sorted to the end.

```
def none_to_end_key(item):
    value = item.data.value if item.data else None
    return (value is None, value)

sorted(items, key=none_to_end_key)
```

Will sort all None values to the end.

I see now that you have tagged your question Python-2.7, then this is probably overkill. In Python 3, comparing None to an integer or string raises an exception, so you can't simply sort a list with None and other values, and something like this is needed.

Comment: Not only is this 3-compatible, but unlike the currently accepted answer, it will put the Nones at the end even if item.data.value has both negative and positive values.  You could even one-line it if you really wanted to (which I don't think is necessary, but some people seem to consider a killer feature for some reason.)

Answer (score 2):

just filter for the None before sorting

```
sorted(filter(None, items), key=attrgetter('data.value'))
```

Comment: Same pinch ;) wise men think alike :D

Comment: I do not want to filter the items.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a function handy that returns the key you want then just write your own.

```
def item_key(item):
    try:
        return item.data.value
    except AttributeError:
        return None

sorted(items, key=item_key)
```

Comment: Could I lambda this? I actually just tried this: `sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.data.value if x.data else None)` Would this be similar to your answer?

Comment: @dabadaba It is not equivalent but it would satisfy the specification too (you did not specify what happens if `item` itself is `None` or if `item.data` is not `None` but it has no `value` attribute or how often `item.data.value` does not exist so I made arbitrary assumptions). I would use a named function in this case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the None values first before sending them to sorted.

```
sorted(filter(None, items), key=attrgetter('data.value'))
```

And if you really want the None items too, you can do something like this:

```
# items already defined with values
new_items_list = sorted(filter(None, items), key=attrgetter('data.value'))
new_items_list.extend([None] * (len(items) - len(new_items_list)))
```

However, I am not sure whether you really need the None items.

EDIT: Fixed the end code which will retain the None items.

Comment: I do need the `None` items.

Comment: The latest edit will give you the None items as well

Answer (score -1):

attrgetter with default value support.

behaves like dictionary.get()

> `D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d`

d defaults to None. detailed info:
[groups.google.com:python-ideas](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-ideas/lc_hkpKNvAg/Pd7Uyt6BUM8J)